# What is the logic behind Start=list in sum()

Tags: python, sum

```
a = sum([[1, 4], [2, 3]],[])

#output = [1, 4, 2, 3]
```

Can please explain how does the start = [] unpack both list? Thanks

Comment: The default for `start` is 0 - which won't work for adding lists.

Comment: This is a **really terrible** way to concatenate lists, by the way - as in, terrible enough to make a program take days when it should take seconds, simply because you did this.

Answer (score 3):

`sum()` adds all elements in the input collection, as if they were joined by the `+` operator. One possible implementation could be something like this:

```
def sum(vals, start=0):
    result = start
    for v in vals:
        result = result + v
    return result
```

Since the default start value is `0`, and `int + list` gives a type error, supplying `[]` as the start value instead will give the expected result.

In the end, `a = sum([[1, 4], [2, 3]],[])` will behave equivalently to:

```
a = []
a = a + [1, 4]
a = a + [2, 3]
```

Comment: it really should be pointed out that this is highly inefficient